# Google App Engine New Free SNI SSL service Clarification

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

In the Google Cloud Platform Live Event, Google announced that App Engine prices are reduced; and in their blog site, they mentioned that App Engine SNI SSL Certificate are free with no charges.

Questions:

1. Does that mean that SSL for App Engine custom domain is free?
2. If so, how can I add it? Currently, Google Apps console requires me to purchase 5 slots for adding SSL.

Thanks!

Comment: link to new Revised plan on appengine https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, to answer my own question, google just updated the page with information about SNI SSL in their developer.google.com page, its still not updated in cloud.google.com page.

Anwer is,  **A up to five SNI SSL certificate slots per month are offered for no additional charge.**

to use it, go to your google apps console-> security-> advanced -> SSL for custom domain-> select appengine id to enable ssl and proceed. done.

Comment: I just went to "SSL for Custom Domains" section in the Google App Admin console, but it still shows "Increase SNI certificate slots by 5 ($9.00 a month)". I thought this was going to be free for the first 5 slots per month, but am I misunderstanding something?

Do you see something different in your admin console?

Thank you,

Comment: Its not active yet i think, they dint mention those changes in developer.google.com site pricing section, but according to the new pricing model, each month 5 SNI SSL slots are free, hope they will add the changes soon!

Comment: Thank you Ramesh.
It still said $9 a month, but I went ahead and added SNI SSL. However I'm not getting billed at the GAE Admin side. So far it looks like it is free as described on other places.

Comment: great, however i couldn't able to add SNI SSL , in google admin console, it says 

** has insufficient budget to add additional SSL resources. Increase the application's daily budget to be able to allocate VIPs or SNI certificate slots.**

even i raised my daily budget to 30$, may i know how much u have in your daily budget ?

Comment: @TacoBurrito and Ramesh, how did you get to actually activate it? I activated it two days ago, and it now says `Applications should be in good standing and have billing enabled to use SSL.`. What does this even mean? I've had billing enabled on my appengine for 4 months, and I set up billing in Apps 32 hours ago (still in 30-day trial). Did you not get this message?

Answer (score 0):

Answering only question 1:
yes, SSL is (and was) free for appid.appspot.com domains. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs or https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_Secure_URLs to turn it on.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl for question 2.

Comment: thats not the question, i know that *.appspot.com ssl is free, i was asking for custom domain SNI SSL certificates, that is the new announced from Google, probably i dint mention it properly